# Как узнать, пересекает ли мой маршрут ТТК

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Проложил маршрут на карте, а теперь можно ли узнать пересекает ли мой маршрут ТТК?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете создать свою геометрию ТТК в виде линии, [получить все сегменты маршрута](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/router) и поверить пересекаются ли они.

Comment: Смотрите есть такой кальк -  http://gruzoperevozrf.ru/calc - Там вводим наши "откуда" и "куда" и получаем маршрут. Мы в данном варианте знаем учитываем МКАД. Но нам нужно просто получать информация пересекает ли наш маршрут ТТК или нет. Достаточно получить эту информацию и записать в переменную

Comment: У вас геометрия МКАДа в виде полигона и примерно то же самое, что я предложил, только вместе мультимаршрута вы используете обычный маршрут. Сделайте дополнительно к геометрии МКАДа геометрию ТТК.